# TYPO3 register icons for specific user group

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

Im using TYPO3 8.7.22

I created an extension which register new icons.

`ext_localconf.php`

```
$boot = function () {
$iconRegistry = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconRegistry::class
);

    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'actions-view',
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:dashboard/Resources/Public/Icons/actions-view.svg']
    );
    $iconRegistry->registerIcon(
        'actions-document-view',
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\SvgIconProvider::class,
        ['source' => 'EXT:dashboard/Resources/Public/Icons/actions-document-view.svg']
    );
};

$boot();
```

Now I want to register them just for specific backend user groups, but the function will be cached and Im unable to check the user group again.

How can I solve it?